# To have/to do in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "to do" in my answer to this question?
"Do you think celebrities have the right to have a private life?"

"Yes, they have the right to do so."

Comment: It's not grammatically wrong, but it sounds odd. "Yes, they have the right to have one" is more idiomatic, or better still "...the right to one" or simply "Yes, they have".

Comment: Is it because *do* is linked to *think* not *have*?

Comment: No, for the reason both answers give - that _do_ and _have_ are different verbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To have* and *to do* are different verbs with different meanings.

"Have a private life" is *passive*, people should just leave them alone.

There is no such phrase as "*doing* a private life" but they could take active measures to remain private. The subtle difference is that celebrities may not have an innate right to a private life, but they would have the right to try.

The best way to avoid that tone shift, is not to change the preposition.

> "Do you think celebrities **have** the right to have a private life?"
>
> "Yes, they **have** that right."

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense as a response to the question because it asks if they have a right to 'have' something, not to 'do' something.

You don't always have to answer a question in the same terms, but when you say something is '*as so*' it is a direct reference to what has been said before.

If the question were about 'doing' something, rather than 'having' something, you could answer that way. For example:

> "Do you think celebrities have the right to **live** a private life?"
> "Yes, they have the right to do so."

Or, you could answer in your own terms, for example:

> "Do you think celebrities have the right to have a private life?"

> "Yes, they have the right to **live privately**."